# Unclear connection information in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, udp, netstat

On Mac OS X (10.9) the `netstat` command in the terminal prints the following. What means `*.*` in this context? Is this a client or a server socket? How can I find out which process opens this connection(s), and for what reason?

```
$ netstat -an
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Adress          Foreign Address        (state)
[...]
udp4       0      0  *.*                   *.*
udp46      0      0  *.*                   *.*
[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `*.*` in the `Local Adress` column for UDP means that the socket hasn't been bound to a specific port.

AFAIK such a socket can't really be used for anything.
If you try to use it for receiving, it won't listen to anything. If you try to use it for sending, it will automatically be bound to a port.

So my only conclusion is that they're sockets kept for sending data, but no data has been sent on them yet (since it's the first call to `sendto` that binds the port).

You can find the process who owns a socket by using `lsof`. It has a lot of filtering options but I usually find it easier to just just grep, like so:

```
sudo lsof -n | grep -F "UDP *:*"
```

The `-n` turns off dns resolution which otherwise might take quite some time.

Edit: It might also be to call `ioctl(..., SIOCGIFMEDIA)` or similar to get network interface information.

Comment: The connection is used by `UserEvent`, which seems to belong to `UserEventAgent`. [Here](http://www.cnet.com/news/about-os-x-system-processes) I've found the following description: "Allows the loading and unloading of system plugins in response to user-generated events, such as plugging in a peripheral device.".
Why this application needs to be able to communicate through a network interface?

Comment: There are several network related plugins in `/System/Library/UserEventPlugins`, e.g. one called `BonjourEvents.plugin` It might also be to get network interface info, as per my edit, but usually the socket is closed directly if so.

Comment: To clarify on the `Foreign Address` `*.*` -- the socket will accept connection from any ip, any port

Answer (score 0):

`*:*` means any IP address, on any network interface.

To find out which process owns which connection, pass `-p` to netstat, e.g. `netstat -anp`. You may need `sudo`.

Comment: "any socket" should be "any network interface" (`IFADDR_ANY`).

Comment: `-p` means something else on osx (it selects protocol, e.g. udp)